# How to compute a probability matrix based on a binary matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, igraph

[image]
**My attempt is:**

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(41)
n<-10

A <- sample.int (2, n*n, TRUE)-1L; dim(A) <- c(n,n); 
m <- sum(A)

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A)

k_in  <- degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "in", loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)#; k_in
k_out <- degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "out", loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)#; k_out

p <- (k_in %*% t(k_out) / (2*m))/(k_in %*% t(k_out) / (2*m) + k_in %*% t(k_out) / (2*m)) 

round(p, 3)
```

All values of probability matrix `p` is 0.5.

I think the error in the denominator of p, because matrix A is not symmetry.

**Question.** How to specify the denominator correctly?

**Edit. After the Stéphane Laurent's answer.**

I think we should have for different value: k_j_out, k_i_in, k_i_out, k_j_in. 
[image]

Finally, I need to obtain the weight matrix, W.

```
I <- matrix(0, n, n); diag(I) <- 1
W <- A %*% (I - P) - t(A) %*% (I - P)
```

And I think this matrix should symmetric.

Comment: mathjax is not supported on stackoverflow. Please edit your question to make it more readable

Comment: @Cettt, I have added the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The `2m` is useless because it appears at both the numerator and the denominator. You can do:

```
p <- (k_in %*% t(k_out))/(k_out %*% t(k_in) + k_in %*% t(k_out))
```

Or, the same with less computations:

```
M <- k_in %*% t(k_out)
M / (M + t(M))
```

## EDIT

We can check:

```
i <- 2; j <- 3
k_out[j] * k_in[i] / (k_out[j] * k_in[i] + k_out[i] * k_in[j])
# 0.5384615
p[i,j]
# 0.5384615
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but I think we should have four different values: k_j_out, k_i_in, k_i_out, k_j_in.

Comment: @Nick You can check this works by computing `k_out[j] * k_in[i] / (k_out[j] * k_in[i] + k_out[i] * k_in[j])`. See my edit.